# Hydrostatic pressure: clarifications

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Hydrostatic pressure is due to the weight of liquid. Do liquid molecules exert pressure on their neighbours molecules or only in objects that are in contact with them?

Answer (score 0):

Pressure in a liquid is transmitted by liquid molecules impacting other liquid molecules. Similarly, pressure is transmitted by liquid molecules impacting objects that are in contact with the liquid.